# How to asses classifier accuracy for objects which belong to multiple classes?

Tags: classification, data-mining

Say I have a dataset where some data object belong to multiple classes simultaneously and I want to evaluate the accuracy of several classifiers based on this dataset. What criteria would I use in order to make a valid answer about the performance of each classifier compared to the others?

Comment: Can you clarify your situation & your data here? Do you mean, eg, that someone could be both male & Asian? Or that someone could be both Asian & African (so-called 'mixed-race')? Or something else?

Comment: I mean just in general, i don't have a specific dataset. But yes, you're example is what I mean.

Comment: Which example? (I gave 2 that weren't consistent w/ each other.)

Comment: Oh sorry, the second one, 'Asian&African'

Answer (score 1):

Someone may have a better answer, but in the past I've treated these cases as heterogeneous classes.

Say I have classes A, B, and C. I have item 1 which belongs to classes A and B. Thus, I now have classes A, B, C, and (A and B).

The pitfall here is that if your classifier gets half of the classification right (let's say we classify item 1 as class A but not B), then it gets marked completely wrong instead of partially wrong.

Comment: You could try to develop a custom loss function to incorporate the idea of *partially wrong*. It's easy to see how this could be applied if you were assessing classification error; I'm less clear how you would use it with something like a Brier score.